# Get the field "Created"

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, javascript, client-object-model, query

I have a list "Consult", and I want get the field "Created"
this is my code:

```
function consultWorkOrder() {

    try
    {   
        var customlist ;
        var clientContext = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();
        var oWebsite = clientContext.get_web();
        var oList = oWebsite.get_lists().getByTitle( 'Work_Order' );    
        var camlQuery = new SP.CamlQuery();

        camlQuery.set_viewXml( '<View><Query><Where><Geq><FieldRef Name=\'ID\'/>' + 
           '<Value Type=\'Number\'>1</Value></Geq></Where></Query></View>' );

        this.customlist = oList.getItems( camlQuery );
        clientContext.load( this.customlist );
        clientContext.executeQueryAsync(            
            Function.createDelegate( this, onQuerySucceededWorkOrder ),
            Function.createDelegate( this, onQueryFailedWorkOrder ));

    }catch(err){
        alert( "Error" );
    }
}

function onQuerySucceededWorkOrder() 
{
        var wo = [];
        var listItemEnumerator = this.customlist.getEnumerator();
        count = 0;


        while ( listItemEnumerator.moveNext() ) 
        {
            var oListItem = listItemEnumerator.get_current();
            wo[count] = { ID: oListItem.get_id(), Status: oListItem.get_item( 'Status0' ) };
            count++;
        }

}

function onQueryFailedWorkOrder( sender, args ) { alert( "Failed" ); }
```

I tried `oListItem.get_item('Created By')` but returns an error..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got the solution:

```
oListItem.get_item( 'Created' )
```

this field contains: "Tue Jun 03 2014 17:01:09 GMT-0300 (Local Standard Time)"

Comment: How can this be a solution the getting the "Created By" field?

Answer (score 0):

The name of that column is "Author", "Created by" is just its display name text.

Comment: no man... i got the solution: `oListItem.get_item( 'Created' )` this field contains: Created: Tue Jun 03 2014 17:01:09 GMT-0300 (Local Standard Time)

Comment: Good to hear that, but your question was about "created by" column, you never mention "Created" column neither a date column...